# Port specific 48 port usb connecting 48 Arduino nano boards to a laptop

Tags: networking, usb, laptop, arduino

I have a rather large and complex design that requires me to send separate sketches / lookup tables to 48 arduino nano boards from my laptop. The laptop is 8 ft from the equipment so SPI won't work. How do I configure a (usb?) network to transfer the data (each different sketch / lookup table to the correct nano)?

Comment: Additionally ... could I put a wifi module on each nano and address them through a wifi net? Can I send and get data from each ip address as well as uploading the sketches?